# React app hosted on Heroku throw 500 Server error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I have a react app which works perfectly on my local Node.JS server. But when I try to use heroku to host it online it throws error and I can't access the website. I think it has something to do with rendering one of my components.

**Heroku CLI Error log:**

```
2020-03-17T18:33:00.452210+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=distributed-care.herokuapp.com request_id=e6b39986-507f-4458-a126-9af86abd2006 fwd="178.221.193.75" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2332ms status=500 bytes=2628 protocol=https
2020-03-17T18:40:04.350680+00:00 app[web.1]: ReferenceError: window is not defined
2020-03-17T18:40:04.350693+00:00 app[web.1]: at new setState (/app/build/static/js/components/SecondaryNav/SecondaryNav.js:32:10)
2020-03-17T18:40:04.350694+00:00 app[web.1]: at i (/app/build/static/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:606:24)
2020-03-17T18:40:04.350695+00:00 app[web.1]: at isValidElement (/app/build/static/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:655:12)
2020-03-17T18:40:04.350696+00:00 app[web.1]: at e.render (/app/build/static/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:811:44)
2020-03-17T18:40:04.350697+00:00 app[web.1]: at e.suspenseDepth [as read] (/app/build/static/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:784:18)
2020-03-17T18:40:04.350697+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.renderToString (/app/build/static/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:668:10)
2020-03-17T18:40:04.350698+00:00 app[web.1]: at routeConfiguration (/app/build/static/js/index.js:113:27)
2020-03-17T18:40:04.350699+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.exports.render (/app/server/renderer.js:95:26)
2020-03-17T18:40:04.350699+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/server/index.js:201:29
2020-03-17T18:40:04.350700+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
2020-03-17T18:40:04.350848+00:00 app[web.1]: server-side-render-failed
2020-03-17T18:40:04.350970+00:00 app[web.1]: undefined
```

So I have tried running the server online without SecondaryNav component, and it works, so SecondaryNav is making issue.

**SecondaryNav.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import classnames from "classnames";
import css from './SecondaryNav.css';

export default class SecondaryNav extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      prevScrollpos: window.pageYOffset,
      visible: true
    };
  }

  // Adds an event listener when the component is mount.
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
  }

  // Remove the event listener when the component is unmount.
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
  }

  // Hide or show the menu.
  handleScroll = () => {
    const { prevScrollpos } = this.state;

    const currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
    const visible = prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos;

    this.setState({
      prevScrollpos: currentScrollPos,
      visible
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={classnames(css.navbar, css.secondaryMenu, {
        [css.navbarHidden] : !this.state.visible
        })}>      
        <ul>
          <li><span>Senior Care</span></li>
          <li><span>Elderly</span></li>
          <li><span>In-home Care</span></li>
          <li><span>Look After</span></li>
          <li><span>Verified</span></li>
          <li><span>See All Categories</span></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**SecondaryNav.css**

```
@import '../../marketplace.css';

.navbar {
    height: 40px;
    transition: height .35s ease-out;
  }

  .navbarHidden {
    height: 0;
  }

  .secondaryMenu {
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(57,73,76,.35);

    @media (max-width: 1170px) {
      display: none !important;
    }

    @media (--viewportLarge) {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: auto;
        background-color: #0095b3;
        box-shadow: -900px 0 0 #f9f9f9, -900px -1px 0 #e0e0e0, 900px 0 0 #f9f9f9, 900px -1px 0 #e0e0e0, 0 -1px 0 #e0e0e0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
  }

  .secondaryMenu ul {
    width: 1170px;
    padding: 0 24px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;

  }

  .secondaryMenu ul li {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 0 2px;
    color: #fff;
  }

  .secondaryMenu ul li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .secondaryMenu ul li span {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
  }
```

What am I doing wrong and is there anyway I can fix this? As I said it works perfectly on my local server but on heroku throws error. I would also appriciate if anyone can just tell me what is caussing the issue.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I have found what was caussing the issue. It was that the server couldn't render the SecondaryNav file as it was using jQuery functions. So the window was a global variable and it wasn't included inside a file.

Fixed file:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import classnames from "classnames";
import css from './SecondaryNav.css';

const hasWindow = (typeof window !== 'undefined') ? true : false;

export default class SecondaryNav extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      prevScrollpos: hasWindow ? window.pageYOffset : null,
      visible: true
    };
  }

  // Adds an event listener when the component is mount.
  componentDidMount() {
    if (hasWindow == true) {
      window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
    }
  }

  // Remove the event listener when the component is unmount.
  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (hasWindow == true) {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
    }
  }

  // Hide or show the menu.
  handleScroll = () => {
    const { prevScrollpos } = this.state;

    const currentScrollPos = hasWindow ? window.pageYOffset : null;
    const visible = prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos;

    this.setState({
      prevScrollpos: currentScrollPos,
      visible
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={classnames(css.navbar, css.secondaryMenu, {
        [css.navbarHidden] : !this.state.visible
        })}>      
        <ul>
          <li><span>Senior Care</span></li>
          <li><span>Elderly</span></li>
          <li><span>In-home Care</span></li>
          <li><span>Look After</span></li>
          <li><span>Verified</span></li>
          <li><span>See All Categories</span></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```